# ruby-aws Amazon Mechanical Turk

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am trying to create a HIT with a pre-created form using the ruby-aws gem and keep getting a missing params error.  I have limited the missing params to the params specific to my form.

It seems my request is not being formatted correctly and there are next to no examples from Amazon.  My logs say the the following params are missing:

relationship, price, environmental_consciousness, age, occasion, gender, humor, experience, local, romance, additional_information

Any help is much appreciated!

Below is my current request:

```
hit = mturk.createHIT(
    :Operation => 'CreateHIT',
    :Title => 'Find a gift based on user scores',
    :Description => 'Find a gift for an individual based on survey scores.',
    :MaxAssignments => 3,
    :Signature => signature,
    :Timestamp => timestamp,
    :Reward => { :Amount => 0.25, :CurrencyCode => 'USD' },
    :HITLayoutId => '3AV6FF2M2GYMGLRQEKHZ7EBN4EZOJE',
    :HitLayoutParameter => {'Name' => 'additional_information', 'Value' => 'TEST'},
    :HitLayoutParameter => {'Name' => 'age', 'Value' => '22'},
    :HitLayoutParameter => {'Name' => 'environmental_consciousness', 'Value' => '54'},
    :HitLayoutParameter => {'Name' => 'experience', 'Value' => '32'},
    :HitLayoutParameter => {'Name' => 'gender', 'Value' => 'male'},
    :HitLayoutParameter => {'Name' => 'humor', 'Value' => '66'},
    :HitLayoutParameter => {'Name' => 'local', 'Value' => '21'},
    :HitLayoutParameter => {'Name' => 'occasion', 'Value' => '43'},
    :HitLayoutParameter => {'Name' => 'price', 'Value' => '33'},
    :HitLayoutParameter => {'Name' => 'relationship', 'Value' => '23'},
    :HitLayoutParameter => {'Name' => 'romance', 'Value' => '23'},  

    :Keywords => 'data collection, gifting, gifts, shopping, gift listings, presents',
    :AssignmentDurationInSeconds => 300,
    :LifetimeInSeconds => 604800
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolive the issue - AWS has terrible naming conventions.  The above example does use the correct format, however HitLayoutParameter must be HITLayoutParameter - Notice the CAPITAL HIT vs Hit.

Also, when submitting multiple parameters, the should only be one HITLayoutParameter that equals an array of Name/Value pairs.  Working code below.

Hope this helps someone else!

Best,

~DFO~

```
hit = mturk.createHIT(
    :Operation => 'CreateHIT',
    :Title => 'Find a gift based on user scores',
    :Description => 'Find a gift for an individual based on survey scores.',
    :MaxAssignments => 3,
    :Signature => signature,
    :Timestamp => timestamp,
    :Reward => { :Amount => 0.25, :CurrencyCode => 'USD' },
    :HITLayoutId => '3AV6FF2M2GYMGLRQEKHZ7EBN4EZOJE',   
    :HITLayoutParameter => [ 
        {:Name => 'additional_information', :Value => 'TEST'},
        {:Name => 'age', :Value => '22'},
        {:Name => 'environmental_consciousness', :Value => '54'},
        {:Name => 'experience', :Value => '32'},
        {:Name => 'gender', :Value => 'male'},
        {:Name => 'humor', :Value => '66'},
        {:Name => 'local', :Value => '21'},
        {:Name => 'occasion', :Value => '43'},
        {:Name => 'price', :Value => '33'},
        {:Name => 'relationship', :Value => '23'},
        {:Name => 'romance', :Value => '23'}
    ],

    :Keywords => 'data collection, gifting, gifts, shopping, gift listings, presents',
    :AssignmentDurationInSeconds => 300,
    :LifetimeInSeconds => 604800
)
```